# What happened with named yields in Meteor/Iron Router?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to use named yields. When I search for it I find examples of how to use them:

Template:

```
{{> yield region="header"}}
```

Controller (Iron Router):

```
...
yieldTemplates: {
    'myHeader': {to: 'header'}
},
...
```

or

```
...
action: function () {
   if (this.ready()) {
      this.render();
      this.render({'myHeader': {to: 'header'}});
   }
},
...
```

However, I tried these, but they just don't work. I checked the [Iron Router docs](http://atmospherejs.com/package/iron-router) and there is no evidence of the existence of **named yields**. 
Does someone know what the current status is of **named yields** ?

Comment: Maybe `yield` is the name of a template in a particular application? In which case the subsequent code `region="header"` sets a property in the template's context?

Comment: That is not the impression I get from [this screencast](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-ironrouter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iron router docs have been re-arranged slightly, perhaps this has happened since you last checked it, it was quite recent.

The section you're looking for is: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md#using-a-layout-with-yields

You might have a typo with your `this.render` with yields, this might work instead:

```
this.render('myHeader', {to: 'header'});`
```

Comment: I indeed had an extra `{` and `}`. Now this.render` works!! Thnx

Comment: I have `yieldTemplates` working to now. It turns out that it doesn't work when you have an `action` defined!